# Check if type is a CLR object

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I am trying to serialize an object and want to know if a certain type can be used by `XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsObject()` or by `ReadElementContentAs()`.

Can I ask a type if it is a CLR type so I know that I can pass it to these methods?

```
if(myType.IsCLRType) // how can I find this property?
    myValue = _cReader.ReadElementContentAsObject();
```

Comment: What do you define as a "CLR type" ? That is not a term with a specific single agreed meaning: so what do *you* mean by that?

Comment: I think I'm looking for this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa669bew.aspx

Comment: In that linked document the term "CLR type" is used to refer to a type which is usable from within the CLR, so in that respect *any* type that you can access from within the CLR is a "CLR type"

Comment: I am just looking for the list that won't give exceptions when I try to use `ReadElementContentAsObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think I'm looking for this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa669bew.aspx

You can probably get most of the way there with `Type.GetTypeCode(type)`, but frankly I expect your best bet is more simple:

```
static readonly HashSet<Type> supportedTypes = new HashSet<Type>(
    new[] { typeof(bool), typeof(string), typeof(Uri), typeof(byte[]), ... });
```

and check with `supportedTypes.Contains(yourType)`.

There is no magic pre-defined list that will match *exactly* the  "this list" you have in mind. For example, `TypeCode` doesn't note `byte[]` or `Uri`.

Comment: Making the list myself is not the problem, but I was hoping for a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like so; if you define the CLR types as being the System Core types.

I'll delete if wrong

```
public static class TypeExtension
{
    public static bool IsCLRType(this Type type)
    {
        var fullname = type.Assembly.FullName;
        return fullname.StartsWith("mscorlib");
    }
}
```

alternatively;

```
    public static bool IsCLRType(this Type type)
    {
        var definedCLRTypes = new List<Type>(){
                typeof(System.Byte),
                typeof(System.SByte),
                typeof(System.Int16),
                typeof(System.UInt16),
                typeof(System.Int32),
                typeof(System.UInt32),
                typeof(System.Int64),
                typeof(System.UInt64),
                typeof(System.Single),
                typeof(System.Double),
                typeof(System.Decimal),
                typeof(System.Guid),
                typeof(System.Type),
                typeof(System.Boolean),
                typeof(System.String),
                /* etc */
            };
        return definedCLRTypes.Contains(type);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isDotNetType = type.Assembly == typeof(int).Assembly;
```

Comment: I like this, heads up though it should be `Int32` or  `int`, not `int32`